# Another root/alias in location produces 403

Tags: nginx

I don't want phpMyAdmin to be in the folder with my site but they should have access on `http://test.example.site` and `http://test.example.site/phpMyAdmin` respectively. But this configuration doesn't seem to work:

- 403 on `http://test.example.site/phpMyAdmin`
- `No input file specified` on `http://test.example.site/phpMyAdmin/index.php`

Configuration is presented below.

```
server {
    server_name test.example.site;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;

    root /home/me/test/www-site;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css;

    client_max_body_size 50m;


    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 1M;
    }

    location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin/ {
            # one of those is included, both don't work
            alias /home/me/test/phpMyAdmin;
            root /home/me/test/;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a request terminated through several sibling [`location`](http://nginx.org/r/location) directives at the same time (unless you do URL rewriting).

- Your request `http://test.example.site/phpMyAdmin` returns `403` because `location /phpMyAdmin/` must not have an index file (the `index` directive from `location /` does not apply), and directory listing must not be permitted.
- Your request `http://test.example.site/phpMyAdmin/index.php` can similarly fit only one location at the same time.  So, it gets handled by the `location ~ \.php`, which has a root of `/home/me/test/www-site`, since the directives from `location /phpMyAdmin/` don't apply.

Similarly, the directives [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) and `root` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well, I mentioned in comment that I don't use `alias` and `root` at the same time. They just both don't work. I copied `index` into `/phpMyAdmin/` sections. Then if I pass non-existed path in `root`, it will say me `No such file or directory`, but if I pass existed path, it will check the files in the global `root`, totally ignoring the `root` I passed in the location. Well, after all how can I rewrite `test.example.site/phpMyAdmin` to match another root and use all other rules like expiration of resources and php files handling? regex + local `root` + `try_files` just don't work.

Comment: You just have to start afresh.  You cannot do what you want the way you want to do it.  It still sounds like what you're trying to do relies on having various *side effects* from past `location` directives; that's basically not how nginx works.